# How to save spacy rendering tags in a dict

Tags: python, nlp, spacy

https://spacy.io/usage/visualizers#ent

I am tryinf to visusalize entities in a sentence by using spaCy. In the link above you can see an example.

Now my question. How can I save those entities in a dictionary?

I want to analyze 100 sentences and save the frequency of those entities to see which terms are the most common.

for example: dict = {"PERSON": 23, "ORG": 2, "LOC": 19}

Can someone help?

Answer (score 0):

You can save the entity labels to a frequency dictionary.

```
import spacy

nlp = spacy.load("en_core_web_lg")
text = "Apple is looking at buying U.K. startup for $1 billion"
doc = nlp(text)
ent_labels = [e.label_ for e in doc.ents]
freq = dict()
for l in ent_labels:
    freq[l] = ent_labels.count(l)
print(freq)
```

Output:

```
{'ORG': 1, 'GPE': 1, 'MONEY': 1}
```